# Read QR Code from file in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm developing a mobile app using the Flutter framework.

I need to read QR Codes, and I have successfully implemented the [Barcode Scan](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/barcode_scan) library, based on [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) to [decode](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/zxing/latest/zxing/Zxing/scan.html) one through the camera.

Now I would also like to add the chance to pick an image containing a QR code from the gallery and decoding, without having to go through the camera.

I checked the library I'm using and also this one without finding any reference to such functionality: [qrcode_reader](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/qrcode_reader), [qr](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/qr).
but in vain.

A solution that would imply serializing and decoding byte by byte an image using pure Dart would be acceptable as well.

Comment: Try barcode detector of [firebase_ml_vision](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_ml_vision). Set barcode format to [QR_CODE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/barcode/FirebaseVisionBarcode.html#FORMAT_QR_CODE)

Answer (score 6):

As I suggested you in my comment you could try using [`firebase_ml_vision`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_ml_vision)package.

Always remember:

> You must also configure Firebase for each platform project: Android
>   and iOS (see the example folder or
>   https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#4
>   for step by step details).

In this example (taken from the official one, but with a specific plugin version - not the latest one) we use [`image_picker`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker) plugin to get the image from device and then we decode the QRCode.

**`pubspec.yaml`**

```
firebase_ml_vision: 0.2.1
image_picker: 0.4.12+1
```

**`detector_painters.dart`**

```
// Copyright 2018 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:firebase_ml_vision/firebase_ml_vision.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum Detector { barcode, face, label, cloudLabel, text }

class BarcodeDetectorPainter extends CustomPainter {
  BarcodeDetectorPainter(this.absoluteImageSize, this.barcodeLocations);

  final Size absoluteImageSize;
  final List<Barcode> barcodeLocations;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double scaleX = size.width / absoluteImageSize.width;
    final double scaleY = size.height / absoluteImageSize.height;

    Rect scaleRect(Barcode barcode) {
      return Rect.fromLTRB(
        barcode.boundingBox.left * scaleX,
        barcode.boundingBox.top * scaleY,
        barcode.boundingBox.right * scaleX,
        barcode.boundingBox.bottom * scaleY,
      );
    }

    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0;

    for (Barcode barcode in barcodeLocations) {
      paint.color = Colors.green;
      canvas.drawRect(scaleRect(barcode), paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(BarcodeDetectorPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.absoluteImageSize != absoluteImageSize ||
        oldDelegate.barcodeLocations != barcodeLocations;
  }
}

class FaceDetectorPainter extends CustomPainter {
  FaceDetectorPainter(this.absoluteImageSize, this.faces);

  final Size absoluteImageSize;
  final List<Face> faces;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double scaleX = size.width / absoluteImageSize.width;
    final double scaleY = size.height / absoluteImageSize.height;

    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0
      ..color = Colors.red;

    for (Face face in faces) {
      canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromLTRB(
          face.boundingBox.left * scaleX,
          face.boundingBox.top * scaleY,
          face.boundingBox.right * scaleX,
          face.boundingBox.bottom * scaleY,
        ),
        paint,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(FaceDetectorPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.absoluteImageSize != absoluteImageSize ||
        oldDelegate.faces != faces;
  }
}

class LabelDetectorPainter extends CustomPainter {
  LabelDetectorPainter(this.absoluteImageSize, this.labels);

  final Size absoluteImageSize;
  final List<Label> labels;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final ui.ParagraphBuilder builder = ui.ParagraphBuilder(
      ui.ParagraphStyle(
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          fontSize: 23.0,
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
    );

    builder.pushStyle(ui.TextStyle(color: Colors.green));
    for (Label label in labels) {
      builder.addText('Label: ${label.label}, '
          'Confidence: ${label.confidence.toStringAsFixed(2)}\n');
    }
    builder.pop();

    canvas.drawParagraph(
      builder.build()
        ..layout(ui.ParagraphConstraints(
          width: size.width,
        )),
      const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(LabelDetectorPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.absoluteImageSize != absoluteImageSize ||
        oldDelegate.labels != labels;
  }
}

// Paints rectangles around all the text in the image.
class TextDetectorPainter extends CustomPainter {
  TextDetectorPainter(this.absoluteImageSize, this.visionText);

  final Size absoluteImageSize;
  final VisionText visionText;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double scaleX = size.width / absoluteImageSize.width;
    final double scaleY = size.height / absoluteImageSize.height;

    Rect scaleRect(TextContainer container) {
      return Rect.fromLTRB(
        container.boundingBox.left * scaleX,
        container.boundingBox.top * scaleY,
        container.boundingBox.right * scaleX,
        container.boundingBox.bottom * scaleY,
      );
    }

    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0;

    for (TextBlock block in visionText.blocks) {
      for (TextLine line in block.lines) {
        for (TextElement element in line.elements) {
          paint.color = Colors.green;
          canvas.drawRect(scaleRect(element), paint);
        }

        paint.color = Colors.yellow;
        canvas.drawRect(scaleRect(line), paint);
      }

      paint.color = Colors.red;
      canvas.drawRect(scaleRect(block), paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(TextDetectorPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.absoluteImageSize != absoluteImageSize ||
        oldDelegate.visionText != visionText;
  }
}
```

**`main.dart`**

```
// Copyright 2018 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_ml_vision/firebase_ml_vision.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

import 'detector_painters.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: _MyHomePage()));

class _MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<_MyHomePage> {
  File _imageFile;
  Size _imageSize;
  dynamic _scanResults;
  String _title = 'ML Vision Example';
  Detector _currentDetector = Detector.text;

  Future<void> _getAndScanImage() async {
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = null;
      _imageSize = null;
    });

    final File imageFile =
    await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (imageFile != null) {
      _getImageSize(imageFile);
      _scanImage(imageFile);
    }

    setState(() {
      _imageFile = imageFile;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _getImageSize(File imageFile) async {
    final Completer<Size> completer = Completer<Size>();

    final Image image = Image.file(imageFile);
    image.image.resolve(const ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
          (ImageInfo info, bool _) {
        completer.complete(Size(
          info.image.width.toDouble(),
          info.image.height.toDouble(),
        ));
      },
    );

    final Size imageSize = await completer.future;
    setState(() {
      _imageSize = imageSize;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _scanImage(File imageFile) async {
    setState(() {
      _scanResults = null;
    });

    final FirebaseVisionImage visionImage =
    FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(imageFile);

    FirebaseVisionDetector detector;
    switch (_currentDetector) {
      case Detector.barcode:
        detector = FirebaseVision.instance.barcodeDetector();
        break;
      case Detector.face:
        detector = FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector();
        break;
      case Detector.label:
        detector = FirebaseVision.instance.labelDetector();
        break;
      case Detector.cloudLabel:
        detector = FirebaseVision.instance.cloudLabelDetector();
        break;
      case Detector.text:
        detector = FirebaseVision.instance.textRecognizer();
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }

    final dynamic results =
        await detector.detectInImage(visionImage) ?? <dynamic>[];

    setState(() {
      _scanResults = results;
      if (results is List<Barcode>
          && results[0] is Barcode) {
        Barcode res = results[0];
        _title = res.displayValue;
      }
    });
  }

  CustomPaint _buildResults(Size imageSize, dynamic results) {
    CustomPainter painter;

    switch (_currentDetector) {
      case Detector.barcode:
        painter = BarcodeDetectorPainter(_imageSize, results);
        break;
      case Detector.face:
        painter = FaceDetectorPainter(_imageSize, results);
        break;
      case Detector.label:
        painter = LabelDetectorPainter(_imageSize, results);
        break;
      case Detector.cloudLabel:
        painter = LabelDetectorPainter(_imageSize, results);
        break;
      case Detector.text:
        painter = TextDetectorPainter(_imageSize, results);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    return CustomPaint(
      painter: painter,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildImage() {
    return Container(
      constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: Image.file(_imageFile).image,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
      child: _imageSize == null || _scanResults == null
          ? const Center(
        child: Text(
          'Scanning...',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.green,
            fontSize: 30.0,
          ),
        ),
      )
          : _buildResults(_imageSize, _scanResults),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          PopupMenuButton<Detector>(
            onSelected: (Detector result) {
              _currentDetector = result;
              if (_imageFile != null) _scanImage(_imageFile);
            },
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<Detector>>[
              const PopupMenuItem<Detector>(
                child: Text('Detect Barcode'),
                value: Detector.barcode,
              ),
              const PopupMenuItem<Detector>(
                child: Text('Detect Face'),
                value: Detector.face,
              ),
              const PopupMenuItem<Detector>(
                child: Text('Detect Label'),
                value: Detector.label,
              ),
              const PopupMenuItem<Detector>(
                child: Text('Detect Cloud Label'),
                value: Detector.cloudLabel,
              ),
              const PopupMenuItem<Detector>(
                child: Text('Detect Text'),
                value: Detector.text,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: _imageFile == null
          ? const Center(child: Text('No image selected.'))
          : _buildImage(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _getAndScanImage,
        tooltip: 'Pick Image',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE for iOS and Android**

to address a successful build on iOS I've got to use an even lower version of `firebase_ml_vision` plugin otherwise you have this [error](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2151).

**`pubspec.yaml`**

```
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2151
firebase_ml_vision: 0.1.2
image_picker: 0.4.12+1
```

And I get the error you have so I've got to modify also my classes.

**`main.dart`**

```
// Copyright 2018 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_ml_vision/firebase_ml_vision.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

import 'detector_painters.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: _MyHomePage()));

class _MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<_MyHomePage> {
  File _imageFile;
  Size _imageSize;
  dynamic _scanResults;
  String _title = 'ML Vision Example';
  Detector _currentDetector = Detector.barcode;

  Future<void> _getAndScanImage() async {
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = null;
      _imageSize = null;
    });

    final File imageFile =
    await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (imageFile != null) {
      _getImageSize(imageFile);
      _scanImage(imageFile);
    }

    setState(() {
      _imageFile = imageFile;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _getImageSize(File imageFile) async {
    final Completer<Size> completer = Completer<Size>();

    final Image image = Image.file(imageFile);
    image.image.resolve(const ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
          (ImageInfo info, bool _) {
        completer.complete(Size(
          info.image.width.toDouble(),
          info.image.height.toDouble(),
        ));
      },
    );

    final Size imageSize = await completer.future;
    setState(() {
      _imageSize = imageSize;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _scanImage(File imageFile) async {
    setState(() {
      _scanResults = null;
    });

    final FirebaseVisionImage visionImage =
    FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(imageFile);

    FirebaseVisionDetector detector;
    switch (_currentDetector) {
      case Detector.barcode:
        detector = FirebaseVision.instance.barcodeDetector();
        break;
      case Detector.face:
        detector = FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector();
        break;
      case Detector.label:
        detector = FirebaseVision.instance.labelDetector();
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }

    final dynamic results =
        await detector.detectInImage(visionImage) ?? <dynamic>[];

    setState(() {
      _scanResults = results;
      if (results is List<Barcode>
          && results[0] is Barcode) {
        Barcode res = results[0];
        _title = res.displayValue;
      }
    });
  }

  CustomPaint _buildResults(Size imageSize, dynamic results) {
    CustomPainter painter;

    switch (_currentDetector) {
      case Detector.barcode:
        painter = BarcodeDetectorPainter(_imageSize, results);
        break;
      case Detector.face:
        painter = FaceDetectorPainter(_imageSize, results);
        break;
      case Detector.label:
        painter = LabelDetectorPainter(_imageSize, results);
        break;
      case Detector.cloudLabel:
        painter = LabelDetectorPainter(_imageSize, results);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    return CustomPaint(
      painter: painter,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildImage() {
    return Container(
      constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: Image.file(_imageFile).image,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
      child: _imageSize == null || _scanResults == null
          ? const Center(
        child: Text(
          'Scanning...',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.green,
            fontSize: 30.0,
          ),
        ),
      )
          : _buildResults(_imageSize, _scanResults),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          PopupMenuButton<Detector>(
            onSelected: (Detector result) {
              _currentDetector = result;
              if (_imageFile != null) _scanImage(_imageFile);
            },
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<Detector>>[
              const PopupMenuItem<Detector>(
                child: Text('Detect Barcode'),
                value: Detector.barcode,
              ),
              const PopupMenuItem<Detector>(
                child: Text('Detect Face'),
                value: Detector.face,
              ),
              const PopupMenuItem<Detector>(
                child: Text('Detect Label'),
                value: Detector.label,
              ),
              const PopupMenuItem<Detector>(
                child: Text('Detect Cloud Label'),
                value: Detector.cloudLabel,
              ),
              const PopupMenuItem<Detector>(
                child: Text('Detect Text'),
                value: Detector.text,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: _imageFile == null
          ? const Center(child: Text('No image selected.'))
          : _buildImage(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _getAndScanImage,
        tooltip: 'Pick Image',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**`detector_painters.dart`**

```
// Copyright 2018 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:firebase_ml_vision/firebase_ml_vision.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum Detector { barcode, face, label, cloudLabel, text }

class BarcodeDetectorPainter extends CustomPainter {
  BarcodeDetectorPainter(this.absoluteImageSize, this.barcodeLocations);

  final Size absoluteImageSize;
  final List<Barcode> barcodeLocations;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double scaleX = size.width / absoluteImageSize.width;
    final double scaleY = size.height / absoluteImageSize.height;

    Rect scaleRect(Barcode barcode) {
      return Rect.fromLTRB(
        barcode.boundingBox.left * scaleX,
        barcode.boundingBox.top * scaleY,
        barcode.boundingBox.right * scaleX,
        barcode.boundingBox.bottom * scaleY,
      );
    }

    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0;

    for (Barcode barcode in barcodeLocations) {
      paint.color = Colors.green;
      canvas.drawRect(scaleRect(barcode), paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(BarcodeDetectorPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.absoluteImageSize != absoluteImageSize ||
        oldDelegate.barcodeLocations != barcodeLocations;
  }
}

class FaceDetectorPainter extends CustomPainter {
  FaceDetectorPainter(this.absoluteImageSize, this.faces);

  final Size absoluteImageSize;
  final List<Face> faces;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double scaleX = size.width / absoluteImageSize.width;
    final double scaleY = size.height / absoluteImageSize.height;

    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0
      ..color = Colors.red;

    for (Face face in faces) {
      canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromLTRB(
          face.boundingBox.left * scaleX,
          face.boundingBox.top * scaleY,
          face.boundingBox.right * scaleX,
          face.boundingBox.bottom * scaleY,
        ),
        paint,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(FaceDetectorPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.absoluteImageSize != absoluteImageSize ||
        oldDelegate.faces != faces;
  }
}

class LabelDetectorPainter extends CustomPainter {
  LabelDetectorPainter(this.absoluteImageSize, this.labels);

  final Size absoluteImageSize;
  final List<Label> labels;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final ui.ParagraphBuilder builder = ui.ParagraphBuilder(
      ui.ParagraphStyle(
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          fontSize: 23.0,
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
    );

    builder.pushStyle(ui.TextStyle(color: Colors.green));
    for (Label label in labels) {
      builder.addText('Label: ${label.label}, '
          'Confidence: ${label.confidence.toStringAsFixed(2)}\n');
    }
    builder.pop();

    canvas.drawParagraph(
      builder.build()
        ..layout(ui.ParagraphConstraints(
          width: size.width,
        )),
      const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(LabelDetectorPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.absoluteImageSize != absoluteImageSize ||
        oldDelegate.labels != labels;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi , I followed the steps and when run there was an error: Unknown type name 'FIRVisionLabelDetector'. Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: @DanielFu Set min sdk to 21 to avoid dex merge errors and set compile and target sdk to 28 for this error in your build.gradle file. Are you trying on Android, aren’t you?

Comment: Actually I’ve just tried on iOS. I”ll check it out in a while

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

flutter plugin: `qr_code_tools`

Pub Link - https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_tools

Home Page - https://github.com/AifeiI/qr_code_tools

Comment: plus 1 for ungoogled solution. Big thanks for Zxing library

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

flutter plugin: `scan`

Pub Link - https://pub.dev/packages/scan

Home Page - https://github.com/flutter-package/flutter_scan

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the below steps to build a simple QR scanner and generator app in Flutter:**

Step 1: First add the following dependency in your pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
   
  path_provider: ^1.6.24
  qr_flutter: ^3.2.0
  barcode_scan_fix: ^1.0.2
```

**Main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
 
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //Given Title
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      //Given Theme Color
      theme: ThemeData(
       primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      //Declared first page of our app
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

**HomePage.dart**

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}
 
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     
      body: Container(
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            //Display Image
            Image(image: NetworkImage("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQyYwscUPOH_qPPe8Hp0HAbFNMx-TxRFubpg&usqp=CAU")),
             
            //First Button
            FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> ScanQR()));
              },
                child: Text("Scan QR Code",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo[900]),),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.indigo[900]),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
 
            //Second Button
            FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>
                                                             GenerateQR()));
              },
              child: Text("Generate QR Code", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo[900]),),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.indigo[900]),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**ScanQR.dart**

```
import 'package:barcode_scan_fix/barcode_scan.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
class ScanQR extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScanQRState createState() => _ScanQRState();
}
 
class _ScanQRState extends State<ScanQR> {
 
  String qrCodeResult = "Not Yet Scanned";
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Scan QR Code"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
    child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: [
      //Message displayed over here
      Text(
        "Result",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      Text(
        qrCodeResult,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.0,
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),
 
      //Button to scan QR code
      FlatButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        onPressed: () async {
          String codeSanner = await BarcodeScanner.scan();    //barcode scanner
          setState(() {
            qrCodeResult = codeSanner;
          });
        },
        child: Text("Open Scanner",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo[900]),),
        //Button having rounded rectangle border
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.indigo[900]),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        ),
      ),
 
         ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**GenerateQR.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:qr_flutter/qr_flutter.dart';
 
class GenerateQR extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GenerateQRState createState() => _GenerateQRState();
}
 
class _GenerateQRState extends State<GenerateQR> {
 
  String qrData="https://github.com/ChinmayMunje";
  final qrdataFeed = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //Appbar having title
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: Text("Generate QR Code")),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
           
          //Scroll view given to Column
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              QrImage(data: qrData),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text("Generate QR Code",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
               
              //TextField for input link
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Enter your link here..."
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                //Button for generating QR code
                child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      //a little validation for the textfield
                      if (qrdataFeed.text.isEmpty) {       
                        setState(() {
                          qrData = "";
                        });
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          qrData = qrdataFeed.text;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                  //Title given on Button
                    child: Text("Generate QR Code",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo[900],),),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.indigo[900]),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```